# Printing a hollow square using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I've been searching around for this question, and have been receiving answers by using purely for-loops. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HollowSquare {


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner ma = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number:");
        int max = ma.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++) {

                if ((i == 1) || (i == max)) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    if (j == 1 || j == max) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

While I understand the concept of recursion, I'm unsure of how to implement it in this area, and at this point, I've been looking at various if statements and using global variables (maybe not the best idea, but I'm relatively new to the concept of recursion).

I want to be able to understand recursion better than I do now, and this is one of the problems that I currently do not understand in terms of recursion.

Thank you to anyone and everyone who is able to help!

Comment: Let's forget about the code for a second. What's is your algorithm for this? How do you draw larger square by drawing smaller ones?

Comment: What do you mean? This takes in an input and prints a square of n height and n width (Ignore the static variables above the main method, forgot to delete those) using asterisks. The first and last rows of the square are filled with asterisk characters while the inside is hollow. I don't understand your question.

Comment: I don’t see a point in using recursion for this task. Of course you can if you must, but I might be able to contribute if you could explain the idea to us.

Comment: I'll try haha. It's an exercise that I've been trying to achieve in recursion after having done for-loops for this small program. It's more to practice the idea of recursion than to make anything bigger out of it, if that makes any sense. The idea here is fairly straight forward: Enter a number, and instead of using for-loops to print out a hollow square of n height and width, recursion is used to create it instead.

Comment: The point is that I know the concept, but I'm hitting a mental block with this problem.

Comment: @OleV.V. I'd love the help. Hopefully my explanations make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of recursion only. I even have one recursive method, `repeatMiddleLine`, call a different method that is in itself recursive, `repeatChar`.

```
public class HollowSquare {

    private static final char squareChar = '*';
    private static final char holeChar = ' ';

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner ma = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Enter the number:");
            int max = ma.nextInt();
            repeatChar(squareChar, max);
            System.out.println();
            repeatMiddleLine(max - 2, max);
            repeatChar(squareChar, max);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void repeatMiddleLine(int lineCount, int lineLength) {
        if (lineCount > 0) {
            System.out.print(squareChar);
            repeatChar(holeChar, lineLength - 2);
            System.out.println(squareChar);
            repeatMiddleLine(lineCount- 1, lineLength);
        }
    }

    private static void repeatChar(char c, int count) {
        if (count > 0) {
            System.out.print(c);
            repeatChar(c, count - 1);
        }
    }

}
```

When I enter 4, it prints:

```
****
*  *
*  *
****
```

Like you I am not doing any input validation. The user may type -30 and I don’t know what the output will be, maybe a couple of blank lines. Or 20000000, and a stack overflow is likely. With input 1 it prints 2 lines each containing an asterisk. I believe you for loops behave better in this case. You can repair it if you want.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help. I really am sorry for having wasted a portion of your time and for pressing you to do this through constant bombardment. To entertain your input validation point, a negative number does absolutely nothing, but that's beside the point. Once again, thank you very much, and I hope you have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to write your recursive method so that it tracks which line you're on for *half* the number of lines, and:

1. writes the appropriate number of stars;
2. calls itself recursively, decrementing the line count;
3. *after* the recursion writes the appropriate number of stars again (which produces the bottom half of the square).

Step (3) is complicated slightly by checking whether you should skip if you're halfway through and have an odd value for `n`, in which case you don't want to write the additional line.

Here it is, written in Ruby.  I didn't want to just give you the answer, and Ruby is practically pseudocode except you can actually run it.

```
def print_all_stars(n)
  puts '*' * n    # print n asterisks on a line
end

def print_end_stars(n)
  puts '*' + (' ' * (n - 2)) + '*'   # print an asterisk, n-2 spaces, and an asterisk
end

# The following method takes two arguments, but the 2nd arg
# has a default value if not explicitly specified.  This negates
# the need for end users to kick-start things by calling
# print_square(n, n), which would probably confuse people.

def print_square(n, current_level = n)
  # recursive base case, start backing out if we're halfway through the square
  return if current_level <= n / 2

  # step 1.
  if current_level == n
    print_all_stars(n)
  else
    print_end_stars(n)
  end

  # step 2.
  print_square(n, current_level - 1)    # recursive call!

  # Work done after the recursive call happens in reverse order,
  # as we back out of the call stack.  The following will print
  # the bottom half of the square, mirroring the top half except
  # for the case where n is odd.  In that case, we only want this
  # level of the recursion to print one line, not two. 

  # step 3.
  if current_level == n
    print_all_stars(n)
  elsif current_level > (n + 1) / 2    # here's the odd n check
    print_end_stars(n)
  end
end

print_square(3)

# produces:
#
#  ***
#  * *
#  ***

print_square(4)

# produces:
#
#  ****
#  *  *
#  *  *
#  ****
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

I am a bit confused: the printSquare Method you wrote takes in two parameters, yet in your demonstration takes only one parameter. Could you explain what is going on?

Comment: Certainly.  The second parameter is being assigned a default value in the declaration.  If you only call the method using one argument, the 2nd arg is assigned the default, with two it uses the value you specify.  The Java equivalent would be to have two identically named methods which take one and two arguments, respectively.  The one-argument method would be the public interface, specifying the size square desired.  The two-argument one would be the recursive one, which tracks which level you're on.  Users shouldn't have to know that the recursion needs two args to work properly.

Comment: So to clarify, there would be two methods, both named printSquare, and the single-parameter one would merely point to the two-parameter version, and in the single parameter version, you would create an int currentValue that would be assigned to the parameter int n?

Comment: Also forgive me, I'm new to translating between languages, and to languages outside of java and a scant amount of VB. When I analyzed the code from ruby to java, all I receive is a string of numbers

Comment: Correct, except that it would only be assigned to the parameter int `n` in the call from the one-parameter version.  The recursive calls would decrement, exactly as in the Ruby version.

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say "analyzed the code from ruby to java, all I receive is a string of numbers."  Are you trying an automated translation?  My intent was that you would learn more about the process by translating a fairly straightforward implementation into your language of choice.

Comment: I looked at the code and implemented it after searching a very basic knowledge of Ruby input output terms.

My issue appears to be in the "puts" lines in the printAllStars and printEndStars methods, where, multiplying the character  * with the int n, and then adding the * with the quantity of a character space multiplied by n-2 and then plus the character star value again:

puts ('*' * n)... and then puts ('*" + (' ' * (n-2)) + '*') returns, when I apply it to System.out.println(), it returns numbers as opposed to stars. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Ah.  In Ruby you can build a string by multiplying a base character times the number of occurrences.  In Java, you need to iterate over the individual characters with `putChar()` or `print()`, whichever makes you happier.  (Just as you did in your question.)  I wrapped the output as methods so the focus would be on how the recursion  cranks out an appropriate set of lines.

Comment: You can try it out and see that it actually works by going to https://repl.it/languages/ruby and pasting the Ruby from my answer.  Then just hit return.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow; I'm so sorry if I'm wasting your time.

Comment: Focus on what's being done, rather than the syntactic details of items such as "how do I print `n` asterisks?"  I've added comments which may help in that regard.